# single schema for multiple collections : MEAN

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have a schema like

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const listSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    id: String,
    hobby: String,
});

const lSchema = module.exports = mongoose.model('lSchema',listSchema,'listone');
```

I want to use this schema/model and want to create another collection MongoDB like listtwo & listthree. Is it possible if yes how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to export it as another schema:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('listSchema', listtwo);
```